# Ubuntu on external HDD cant be opened/renamed. How fix this?

Tags: 14.04, windows-10, usb-drive, external-hdd, disk-management

Got an old HDD with Ubuntu installation on it.

Connected it via USB into my Win10 system.

Disk Management, Crystal Disk Info etc do recognize the external drive and claim it healthy. Still I cant open it, rename the drive letter or else.

My aim is just so save my data from the old Ubuntu, then format the whole drive. (which will make it usable as ext drive hopefully)

Could I just boot from the USB-drive and copy/paste my data or will this cause any troubles? Is there simpler solution within Windows maybe?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Windows can't read the drive because the file system is in `ext4` format (or possibly `ext3`) that Windows doesn't understand. However, there is some freeware available that allows you to read an ext4 drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot from a live Ubuntu DVD/USB. Then you will be able to read data from that drive and also copy it to your Windows drive.

Comment: this means I can access the files within Ubuntu inside its install-process? I just tried booting from it, which worked but I wasnt able to connect my USB-drive to copy/paste my files unfortunately

Comment: Don't start the install process, just boot the live system. Then connect your USB drive, the system should detect it (you should get the icon of the new drive somewhere) and you should be able to open it. Similarly the system should detect your Windows partition and you should be able to open it. Then copy/paste should work.